# Where is libHSprimitive-0.5.3.0.so

Tags: haskell, mflow

Trying to install MFlow on linux mint.  sudo cabal install MFlow gives me this:

Loading package primitive-0.5.3.0 ... : can't load .so/.DLL for: libHSprimitive-0.5.3.0.so (libHSprimitive-0.5.3.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
Failed to install vector-0.10.9.2

cabal tells me that I do have primitive-0.5.3.0 installed.  Any hope of getting this to happen?

Thanks much for any help!

Comment: What are the versions of everything you are using? Does your .cabal file contain `shared: False`?

Comment: Why are you using "sudo"?  Cabal, by default will put files in your home directory.  It is possible that this is related to your problem, perhaps permissions or locations are getting confused by running as root part of the time.  Can you find libHSprimitive-0.5.3.0.so in "~/.cabal/lib/......" anywhere?

Comment: @user2407038 >> Why are you using "sudo"? <<   Because when I did cabal install cabal-install, it failed, but when I did sudo cabal install cabal-install, it succeeded.  I have tried the cabal install MFlow both with and without the sudo, same result.  I've got ./primitive-0.5.3.0/ghc-7.8.2/libHSprimitive-0.5.3.0_p.a and 
./primitive-0.5.3.0/ghc-7.8.2/libHSprimitive-0.5.3.0.a, but no matching .so.  Looks like shared: False is commented out in ~/.cabal/config; I see -- shared: False.  I installed ghc 7.8.2 yesterday, updated everything I could with apt-get update/upgrade and cabal yesterday too

Answer (score 14):

I ran into the exact same issue.  So here's some elaboration on the problem.

The comment by user2407038 provided the answer.  By default, `shared` is set to `False` so shared libraries are not built.  This means any libraries that expect to link to the shared library `libHSprimitive-*.so` would fail to build.

The solution was to reinstall `primitive` with `shared` set to `True`.  You can do this either by modifying `~/.cabal/config` or by passing an extra argument:

```sh
cabal install --reinstall --enable-shared primitive
```